# Удаление данных через POST запрос из Moq объекта

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, httpclient, moq

Я сделал вот такой объект moq.

```
private void MockObject()
        {
            mock.Setup(n => n.Categories).Returns(new List<Category>()
            {
                new Category() {Id = "b0df116c-66d3-4c4d-be0d-a74e966f769b", Name = "Bosh", Prefix = "B_"},
                new Category() {Id = "a37f1d26-f7a6-4772-a6fa-dbc17b056da2", Name = "Bosh2", Prefix = "B2_"},
                new Category() {Id = "c0bed713-4f14-4b78-8303-d1505a7b1d93", Name = "Bosh3", Prefix = "B3_"}
            });
        }
```

в Index всё работает. То есть данные отображаются.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            MockObject();

            return View(mock.Object.Categories);
        }
```

Хочу сделать, что бы и метод Delete тоже работал с этими данными.
Сделал так:

```
/// GET: Categories/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        MockObject();
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var category2 = mock.Object.Categories.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        var category = await _context.Categories
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (category2 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(category2);
    }

    // POST: Categories/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
    {
        var category2 = mock.Object.Categories.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        var category = await _context.Categories.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        //mock.Object.Categories.
        _context.Categories.Remove(category);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

GET Методе всё работает.
А, вот в POST не работает, не пойму, на что нужно заменить эти строчки:
`_context.Categories.Remove(category);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`.

**И вообще возможно ли это сделать?**

Comment: Моки нужны для юнит-тестов. У вас же я вижу мок-объекты прямо в коде контроллеров. Бред какой-то... Вы должны создать мок-объект, заменяющий собой репозиторий. И этот мок использовать вместо настоящего репозитория (чтобы в реальную БД не обращаться).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  Это не для тестирования. Понятное дело, что можно и в базу тогда обратиться и moq не нужен!

Comment: @Alexander Petrov А, вот про мок-объект как репозиторий это как раз то что нужно! Можно по подробней.

Comment: Моки применяются именно для тестирования, только для тестирования. | Юнит-тесты никогда в реальную базу не лезут (это долго и можно повредить реальные данные).

Comment: Я попробую написать ответ, но тут нужно и суть модульного тестирования объяснить, и про инъекцию зависимостей рассказать. В общем, ждать придется долго...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если вы напишите ответ, это очень хорошо! Я подожду. Очень нужная информация. Я новечёк в мок! Хотел использовать его к примеру если бызы ещё нет но нужно увидеть как это выглядит. Думаю в основно для этого. Так же иногда нужно сносить базу что бы подправить. Но для быстрой проверки можно и мок воспользоваться, посмотреть и потом уже базу сделать. Просто хотелось иметь весь функционал. Если понадобиться.

Comment: _если базы ещё нет_ - согласен, для этого моки тоже применяются, я был неправ выше.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я буду ждать ответ! Надеюсь вы не передумали писать!

Comment: Я о вас не забыл. Но всё оказалось намного сложнее, чем я предполагал. Мне не удалось найти готового _работающего_ решения для моканья `DbContext` (на nuget/github есть только сырые заготовки, не обеспечивающие полный функционал) EF Core. А выписывать все моки для всех методов вручную - нужны тонны кода.

Comment: Судя по всему, `_context` в вашем коде - это наследник `DbContext`. Его хрен замокаешь (см. выше)... Особенно с учётом асинхронных методов. Но можно попробовать замокать _репозиторий_, внутри которого может использоваться такой контекст. У вас есть хотя бы наброски репозитория?

Comment: _иногда нужно сносить базу_ - если нужно поработать с тестовой БД, которая в дальнейшем не нужна, то можно создавать её в памяти (in memory). Во всяком случае, если используется современная версия SqlServer. Это и для тестов годится, т. к. работает быстро.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Репозиториев увы нет, кроме ICategoryRepository в котором  IEnumer....<Category>  и класс CategoryRepo... который наследуется от интерфейса и get ом получает данные через context. Да, и для данной проблемы , я тоже пришёл к выводу, что Moq мне не подойдёт. Попробовал несколько вариантов решения. Но все они за собой тянули зависимости и так без конца. Так что я тоже склоняюсь к методу InMemory. Пока не очень понимаю как и что, но думаю нужно посмотреть! Спасибо за что не забыли! Но думаю пока Moq отложу! Но если, где то найдёте решение, прошу написать или ссылку кинуть!